# sql request generator, dynamically generation of where clause

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql

I want to create a mini lib for generating my sql request (in javascript with nodejs), I want to make something modular, but my problem is managing OR and AND, since you can sometimes make some nested request like

```
(condition AND ( (condition OR condition) AND (condition OR condition) ))
```

So before I get started I was wondering if there is some clean way to manage the example above, maybe some factorisation or some cool design pattern but I found nothing like that, thanks !

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "way to manage". What is not clear here?

Comment: You can, sometimes make a request like 'cond and cond or cond'. That would be leagal request. Request like 'cond and (cond or cond)' also is legal. What is your point?

Comment: Look how other ORMs do that, e.g. https://sequelize.org/master/manual/querying.html

Comment: I just want to find a clean way to give the possibility to a user to generate a request like the one in my question, via some function or object in my lib.
Indeed I'll go look out for how other ORM do that, that'll help me !